# keep the track of all files according to their last updated date using stack implementation

Tags: c, data-structures, stack

I want to keep the track of  all files according to their last updated date using stack implementation. If I am taking three variables one for date, month and year then i am not getting how to push them on stack . I am coding in c.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use a struct to store the date, month, and year together for each file, then push the structs onto the stack in the appropriate order.

```
struct {
    int day, month, year;
} fileData;
```